# Failing to install my flutter app to my iPad

Tags: ios, flutter

I fail to install my flutter app to my iPad and I wonder what could cause this.

I am using automatically signing and is kind of lost what is actually needed to get this to work.

I.e. I can't see that I have added my iPhone device anywhere, where I also should add my iPad.

## Installing to my iPhone works

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Gunnars iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: HZ4ZKW97SC
Running pod install...                                              9,5s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           32,1s
Installing and launching...                                        24,2s
Debug service listening on ws://localhost:1024/ws
Syncing files to device Gunnars iPhone...
```

## Installing to my iPad fails

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Gunnars iPad in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: HZ4ZKW97SC
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           29,6s
Installing and launching...





Installing and launching...                                        17,7s
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for
your team by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected.
     - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
     - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/setup/#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-07-04 10:38:32.180 ios-deploy[93017:5221164] [ !! ] Error 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008027-001D098C0A87002E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Gunnars iPad.
```

## Managed to install to iPad from xcode

I followed th advice to try to run from with in xcode and then I managed to install the app to my iPad.

But when efter that trying from flutter/intellij I get the following ...

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Gunnars iPad in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: HZ4ZKW97SC
Running pod install...                                              9,0s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           142,2s
Installing and launching...                                     





Installing and launching...                                        16,3s
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Error launching app. Try launching from within Xcode via:
    open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version.
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-07-04 12:20:06.647 ios-deploy[68752:5425107] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000022: The service is invalid. AMDeviceSecureStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), NULL, &con)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008027-001D098C0A87002E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Gunnars iPad.
```

Comment: Seeing the same issue.
Xcode 14.2
iPad iOS 14.2
runs correctly from Xcode, fails when run from VSCode / flutter run